# how to send email in server using core php?

Tags: php

I have written a email send php code and uploaded onto server. It is working and email is being send to the inbox. But when i uploaded the same code onto another server, it is not working, mail is not being send but the message "your message has been send successfully" is being displayed. why is it like that ? Can anyone tell ?

Comment: can you share some of your codes?

Comment: Most likely because your server isn't configured to send emails.

Comment: how to configure the server ?

Comment: How can we possibly know what's wrong with your server or your code?  You know we're not actually talking to you from inside your computer, right?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of shared webhosting providers who have disabled PHP's `mail()` function.

WHat you could do is switch to, for example: [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: when i am using phpgmailer this error is showing "fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Permission denied) in /home/www/xxxxxx/website/phpgmailer/class.smtp.php on line 105
ErrorSMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. " . can anyone say wht this error is ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing you code i'ts not possible to tell you why it isn't working.

You say your getting the message "your message has been send successfully" but that isn't the response from the send() command - that should be a boolean -  so check that your code is reading that correctly and reporiting the correct result.

If the send() is returning true then it means your message has left the server but doesn't mean it's arrived at it's destination. Most likely the recipients server is blocking your new server for some reason.

My suggestion is to use an external SMTP server to send the mail through so it's consistent across where ever your app is hosted. Amazon SES is very good, cheap and allows you to easily monitor bounces too.

Answer (score -1):

This is my code for phpgmailer. This is showing the above error.

```
       <?php


    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    $telephone = $_POST['phone'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $msg = $_POST['message'];


    require_once("phpgmailer/class.phpgmailer.php");
     $mail=new PHPGMailer();
  $mail->Username="cd4xltech";
   $mail->Password="dfddfdfddf";
   $mail->From="cd4xltech@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName=$name;
  $mail->Subject="Feedback:".$subject;
      $mail->AddAddress("annan@gmail.com");
    $mail->Body=$message."From: $name";
     if(!$mail->Send())
     {
echo "Error".$mail->ErrorInfo;
         }
     else
   {
echo "Mail Sent";
        }


       ?>
```